# Why does GridLines option fail with Function?

Tags: plotting, graphics, front-end, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

The `Plot` option [`GridLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines.html) can be specified either as a list of explicit values at which to draw the lines, or as a **function** that calculates the grid lines based on the maximum and minimum values along each axis. In *Mathematica* version 8, I was able to specify this function for `GridLines` in two equivalent ways:

```
Clear[gridLineFunction];
gridLineFunction[xmin_, xmax_] := {.1, .2, .5};

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, GridLines -> gridLineFunction]
```

[image: lines]

This follows the example in the documentation, but for simplicity it returns a fixed list of numbers without doing any calculations at all. However, now I rewrite the above by passing it directly to `GridLines` as a `Function`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 GridLines -> Function[{xmin, xmax}, {.1, .2, .5}]]
```

[image: no lines]

This last line is what I get in **version 10** on OS X. It *used to work* in version 8. And the equivalent construct *still works* for the `Ticks` option:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> Function[{xmin, xmax}, {.1, .2, .5}]]
```

[image: ticks]

Is there any reason I'm overlooking why this `Function` approach no longer works in `GridLines`, or is this a bug?

Comment: In version 8.0.4 under Win7 x64 your code with `GridLines -> Function[...]` gives [this](http://i.imgur.com/Pr37b7P.png). Looks like a bug in v.10.0.0.

Comment: Works fine on _v8_ Linux as well.

Comment: Ouch. It has been reported.

Comment: @rcollyer I do hope point release updates are still included with Home Edition. :-O

Comment: @rcollyer Is there the possibility of a fix for this that can be applied the current version?  The fact that it is Front End code makes it hard to work on (for me) but I'd really like to get this working sooner rather than later.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard the fix is in the upcoming point release. As to applying it to the current release, that would be involved, and not easily doable.

Comment: @rcollyer Okay.  Any idea how long I'll need to wait?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes. But, I don't have specific dates, nor can I talk about them. Soon, I suspect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the meantime, here is a way to repair the gridlines

```
fixGridLines[plot : _Graphics | _Legended] :=
  Module[{xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax},
   {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = 
    Through[{Min, Max}[#]] & /@ 
     Transpose@Cases[plot, {_Real, _Real}, Infinity];
   With[{p = plot}, MakeBoxes[p, StandardForm]] /. 
    pat : (GridLines -> {Charting`ScaledTickValues[_, xf_[_]] &, 
         Charting`ScaledTickValues[_, yf_[_]] &}) :> 
     GridLines -> {xf[xmin, xmax], yf[ymin, ymax]}
   ] // ToExpression
```

Example:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
   GridLines -> Function[{xmin, xmax}, {.1, .2, .5}]];
fixGridLines[plot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can examine the box form of the plot to see where the `GridLines` functions got stored.

---

**Edit:** *Other ways to get the plot range.*

This includes `PlotRangePadding` in the computation (might be best of all):

```
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = 
  Charting`get2DPlotRange[Replace[plot, p_Legended :> First@p]];
```

This does not include `PlotRangePadding`:

```
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = With[{p = plot},
   PlotRange /. Cases[MakeBoxes[p, StandardForm], pat : (PlotRange -> _), Infinity]
   ]
```

Comment: Yes, this is a work-around. I would just include `Legended` as an allowed `Head` for the `plot` argument, because otherwise it won't work with the `PlotLegends` options.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the tip.  `Legended` now included.

Comment: I accepted this because that's probably the best we can do - after all, it's still a bug... but now it's clearer what caused it.

Comment: @Jens Thanks, I realize it is not a complete explanation.  I just thought it might be helpful for others.