# How to get grid lines at all (log) tick marks in Version 10?

Tags: plotting, bugs, ticks, logarithmic-scale

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.1.0**

---

#### *Update:*

- It seems that only versions 10.0.0, 10.0.1, and 10.0.2 are affected by this problem.
- For 10.0.0 there is no general solution known to me due to [Why does GridLines option fail with Function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54578/121)
- For versions 10.0.1 and 10.0.2 a solution is the `PlotTheme` method in my [self-answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60108/121).
  (The **enhanced definition** in that answer may still be of general interest.)
- In version 10.1.0 and later both `GridLines -> All` and `GridLines -> Full` produce the desired result, as shown in pmsoltani's [now Accepted answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108685/121).

---

In Version 7 using `GridLines -> Automatic` (or `All`) would put a grid line at every log-spaced tick mark:

```
LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5},
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

In Version 10 this is no longer the case:

[image]

What is the simplest way to recover the old behavior?

Comment: Nice plot from Version 7, why did WRI remove this features from `LogPlot`? But trying something I think I found a problem. Posting question now :)

Comment: @Nasser I suppose they consider the new form more clean, but I rely on that feature to clearly see the values on log plots.  If there is no simple method I'll have to code a `GridLines` function to do it.

Comment: I was trying to do that, using `GridLines->function` but I think there is a bug, please see question I just asked on this.

Comment: Are we tagging the howto in v10 questions with [tag:version-10] or is that going to get cumbersome quickly?

Comment: @bobthechemist Please untag them when you see them... I don't know who started this trend, but that is not how we were doing things before. A exceptions can be made when it has been confirmed as a bug by the community

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can, also, use `GridLines -> Full` option (in version 10.3, at least):

```
LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5},
GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
GridLines -> Full, 
Frame -> True]
```

[image: semilog plot with full girdlines]

Comment: This works in v10.1.0 as well.  Thanks!  In version 10.1.0 `GridLines -> All` also works.  I am inclined to think that this may have been a transitory bug.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I get `A GridLines specification should be None, Automatic, or a list of grid line specifications.` M 10.0.0.0

Comment: @William Thank you.  I recall trying (guessing) multiple alternative values in 10.0.0 before posting this question, so I probably didn't simply forget to try `Full`.  Do you happen to also have access to v10.0.1?  That is when the bug fix necessary for my self-answer solution was made, therefore if `Full` *does not* work in 10.0.1 my answer still has value, but if it does it fully supplants my method.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No I do not.  I'm amazed that such changes occurred between the versions of 10.0.0 and 10.0.1 although it is a bug.

Comment: @William I reinstalled 10.0.1 and 10.0.2 just to check this.  Neither `All` nor `Full` work.  I am updating the question post with the aim of directing users to the best solution.

Comment: @Mr. I think we should tag this as a bug and add the bug header.

Answer (score 18):

Now that specifying a `GridLines` function has [been repaired](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54578/121) we can use this:

```
logticks[a_, b_] := First /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][a, b] // Exp;
```

Note that a slightly different option value is needed for each plot type.  One could make these options the default using `SetOptions`, but if you prefer to keep the existing default and simplify application of this style I propose a [custom](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54545/121) `PlotTheme`:

```
MapThread[
  Themes`AddThemeRules["LogGrid", #, GridLines -> #2, Frame -> True] &,
  {
    {LogPlot | ListLogPlot, LogLinearPlot | ListLogLinearPlot, LogLogPlot | ListLogLogPlot},
    {{Automatic, logticks}, {logticks, Automatic}, logticks}
  }
];
```

Now you can enable this style for any log plot using `PlotTheme -> "LogGrid"`:

```
LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5},
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotTheme -> "LogGrid", Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
LogLinearPlot[Log @ x, {x, 1, 500},
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotTheme -> "LogGrid", Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
LogLogPlot[x, {x, 0.1, 15},
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotTheme -> "LogGrid", Frame -> True]
```

[image]

---

### Enhanced definition

*I am finally updating this to answer rcollyer's challenge back in May.*

To provide some additional contrast one might wish to style the major division grid lines differently.  This will require more elaborate code, but first examples of use:

The Theme used with a parameter:

```
LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}, PlotTheme -> {"LogGrid", {Thick, Red}}]
```

[image]

Or by setting a global Option:

```
SetOptions[logticks, "MajorStyle" -> {Thick, Orange, Opacity[0.5]}];

LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}
  , GridLinesStyle -> LightGray
  , PlotTheme -> "LogGrid"
]
```

[image]

The code needed to effect this:

```
Options[logticks] = {"MajorStyle" -> {}};   (* uniform style by default *)

logticks[a_, b_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Replace[
  Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][a, b],
  {{p_, _Spacer, ___} :> Exp[p],
   {p_, ___}          :> {Exp[p], OptionValue[logticks, "MajorStyle"]}},
  {1}
 ]

logticks[mstyle_][a_, b_] := logticks[a, b, "MajorStyle" -> mstyle]

makeTheme = (
  System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["LogGrid", #] := 
    Themes`SetWeight[{GridLines -> #2, Frame -> True}, 
      System`PlotThemeDump`$ComponentWeight];
  System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme[{"LogGrid", mstyle_}, #] := 
    Themes`SetWeight[{GridLines -> (#2 /. logticks -> logticks[mstyle]), 
       Frame -> True}, System`PlotThemeDump`$ComponentWeight];
 ) &;

MapThread[makeTheme, {
   {"LogPlot" | "ListLogPlot", 
    "LogLinearPlot" | "ListLogLinearPlot", 
    "LogLogPlot" | "ListLogLogPlot"},
  {{Automatic, logticks}, {logticks, Automatic}, logticks}
}];
```

Comment: You could add a parameterization to your theme. For example, `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> {"Monochrome", Red}] `. And, no I don't know how it is implemented, but I imagine that won't stop you. :)

Comment: @rcollyer Interesting challenge.  I'll try to remember to see if I can do it.

Comment: @rcollyer Please see my belated update.

Comment: Nice. Even works combined with other themes, e.g. `LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}, 
 PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", {"LogGrid", {Red, Dashed, Opacity[1]}}}]`.

Answer (score 8):

```
LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 GridLines -> {Range[5], 
   Flatten[Table[n, {n, 1 #, 9 #, 1 #}] & /@ (10^Range[0, 4])]}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Gridlines in LogPlot]

Comment: The problem is that hard-coded grid lines have to be adjusted manually for every individual plot.

Comment: Of course I agree.  I am in fact very unhappy with the various `Log???Plot` functions.  In my opinion there should be a single `Plot` (and a single `Plot3D`) function, which is supplemented by `ScalingFunction->{"Lin", "Log"}` or something very similar.

Comment: That would indeed be very nice. There are so many new finance related charting functions etc., but no progress in actual scientific plotting.

Comment: @ErnstStelzer Apparently we have that now, or the easy ability to implement it, as `ParametricPlot` supports `ScalingFunctions` (unofficially).  See Simon Woods' answer: [(55882)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55882)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you very much for the hint.  It actually works inside `Plot`.  I managed to crash the kernel with some combinations but `"Reverse"` worked too.

Comment: In case you care I now have a fairly general solution for version 10.0.1.  See my self-answer.