# How to transpose x and y axes on a LogPlot?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Consider the following simple LogPlot:

```
LogPlot[Exp[x],{x,0,5}]
```

[image: LogPlot of Exp[x]]

Is there a nice way to switch the axes of a LogPlot?

I'm aware that plotting the inverse function as follows

```
LogLinearPlot[Log[y],{y,Exp[0],Exp[5]}]
```

will do the job. The actual function I'm using is more complicated so I want to avoid using the inverse if possible.

I've tried the various methods here

[How can I transpose x and y axis on a Plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/how-can-i-transpose-x-and-y-axis-on-a-plot)

but they would seem to require some modification in order to work.

Comment: Would you explain the reason you wish to avoid the solution included in your question?

Comment: The main reason is that it would be cumbersome and more difficult to follow. I imagine someone not familiar with Mathematica would be confused about why I am going to pains to plot the inverse function. It does not help that my function inverse is multi-valued.

Comment: That makes sense.  Incidentally I asked not because I thought this was a bad question, but because without understanding why that solution should be avoided I (or someone else) might recommend another one with the same detractions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would a `ListPlot` style solution work for you as in the following:

```
ListLogPlot[Table[{x, Abs[Gamma[x]]}, {x, -5, 2, 0.01}], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

and it's "transpose"

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{Abs[Gamma[x]], x}, {x, -5, 2, 0.01}], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know about ListLogPlots. For my purposes, this method is simple and works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) to transpose the axes by plotting $\{y,x\}$, and [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) to get the log scale:

```
ParametricPlot[{Abs[Gamma[x]], x}, {x, -5, 2},
 PlotTheme -> "Business",
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", Identity}]
```

[image]

Note that `ScalingFunctions` does not appear to be officially supported for `*Plot` functions so this should be regarded as undocumented behaviour and may change in future releases.

Comment: Alas I have Mathematica 8.0 and ScalingFunctions does not seem to be supported in this version. Looks good though!

Answer (score 6):

I was working on my solution and then I saw bobthechemist's answer, which is much better than mine. However, if you insist on using `LogPlot`(and not `ListLogPlot`) for your original plot, here's what I would do to transpose it:

**1)** Note that if you evaluate `gammaPlot = LogPlot[Abs[Gamma[x]], {x, -5, 2}];
gammaPlot // InputForm`, the internal representation of your `gammaPlot` curve are the pairs of points within the `Line` function. In fact, there are 4 separate `Line`'s in the curve as it breaks at x = -2, x = -1, and x= 0 (not sure why the curve doesn't break at the other negative integer values).

**2)** To extract these points, I use `Cases` with a transformation rule involving `Reverse` to switch the x and y plot points. You can just use `Line[points_]` to pick out the pattern since all the points are nested within a huge list anyway, but I decided to hash out the pattern structure in more detail to illustrate the use of `Map`.

```
Cases[gammaPlot, 
 Line[points : {{_, _} ..}] :> Reverse /@ points, Infinity]
```

**3)** Since Log (natural log) was applied to the y values to produce the y plot points of the `LogPlot`, I use `Exp[y]` in a transformation rule to restore the y-values (which are now the horizontal/x values). I then used `ListLogLinearPlot` (with the `Joined -> True` option to connect the points) to display the final curve. As you can see the 4 `Line` sections are reproduced.

```
ListLogLinearPlot[% /. {y_, x_} :> {Exp[y], x}, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

***Sidenote***: to make the plot one color, just apply `Join` to combine the `Line`'s together. Warning: doing so might artificially connect any discontinuities in your plot. Therefore, I'd recommend leaving `Join` out and instead specify the overall look of your plot using `PlotStyle` at the end.

```
ListLogLinearPlot[
 Join @@ Cases[gammaPlot, 
    Line[points : {{_, _} ..}] :> Reverse /@ points, Infinity] /. {y_,
     x_} :> {Exp[y], x}, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**One-step solution to plot the inverse of a `LogPlot` curve on a `ListLogLinearPlot`**

```
Clear[inverseLogPlot]
inverseLogPlot[f_, {xp_, xmin_?NumericQ, xmax_?NumericQ}, 
  options___] := 
 With[{originalPlot = LogPlot[f, {xp, xmin, xmax}]}, 
  ListLogLinearPlot[
   Cases[originalPlot, 
     Line[points : {{_, _} ..}] :> Reverse /@ points, 
     Infinity] /. {y_, x_} :> {Exp[y], x}, Joined -> True, options]]
inverseLogPlot[Abs[Gamma[x]], {x, -5, 2}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Comparison with bobthechemist's method**

Bob's method is much more comprehensible and intuitive than my method, so I would suggest you to use that method if you need to plot something quick. However, one advantage of my method--and please let me know if I'm mistaken--is that it uses the adaptive sampling of MMA when it plots a function ([ref](http://wolfram.com/xid/0e7qll8y-gcw27j)):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This could be seen by comparing my transposed plot to that of Bob. The peaks of my plot go much higher than Bob's  to reflect the fact that f[x] goes to infinity at negative integer values of x.

```
Clear[bobLogPlot]
bobLogPlot[f_, {xp_, xmin_?NumericQ, xmax_?NumericQ}, options___] :=
 ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{f, xp}, {xp, xmin, xmax, 0.01}], 
  Joined -> True, options]
TableForm[{LogPlot[#, {x, -5, 2}, Frame -> True],
    inverseLogPlot[#, {x, -5, 2}, Frame -> True],
    ListLogPlot[Table[{x, #}, {x, -5, 2, 0.01}], Joined -> True, 
     Frame -> True],
    bobLogPlot[#, {x, -5, 2}, Frame -> True]} &@Abs[Gamma[x]], 
 TableHeadings -> {{"LogPlot", "inverseLogPlot (transposed)", 
    "ListLogPlot", "bobLogPlot (transposed)"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Edit**: this plot should show how `LogPlot` is sampled differently from `ListLogPlot`. Please delete if unnecessary.

```
Show[
 LogPlot[Abs[Gamma[x]], {x, -5, 2},
  PlotLegends -> 
   Style["LogPlot[Abs[Gamma[x]],{x,-5,2}]", Red]~Placed~Above,
  PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> All, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[0.7]]],
 ListLogPlot[Table[{x, Abs[Gamma[x]]}, {x, -5, 2, 0.01}], 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Style["ListLogPlot[Table[{x,Abs[Gamma[x]]},{x,-5,2,0.01}]]", Blue]~
    Placed~Below, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, AbsolutePointSize[0.7]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 - I like exploring the internals of graphics (complexes) in mma.  I agree that adaptive sampling is the main advantage of your route, as creating a table with a fine step size could become cumbersome.

Comment: This is a nicely written function and well-explained! I like that you have managed to keep the properties of LogPlot, especially adaptive sampling. For my purposes - I have no sharply changing gradients, so I have chosen bobthechemist's simpler method. Why Wolfram can't simply implement this as an option in their Plot functions..