# Vertical GridLines do not show in version 11 when using Ticks

Tags: ticks, version-11, grid-lines

I googled this and do not see it.  I noticed when I use `Ticks ->` with `GridLines`, then the vertical `GridLines` no longer show up.  This is on version 11.01 on windows 7, 64 bit.

I tried the same MWE on 10.4, same PC, and there the vertical lines show up!

Here is MWE. Running on 11.01

```
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 6 Pi},
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 6 Pi, Pi], Automatic}]
```

Here is the output

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the same thing on 10.4:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see that now the vertical lines show up.

Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround? (I did not tag it as bug)

Comment: Probably another `GridLines` bug; you could approach it as I did here: [(60108)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60108/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference arises when using `Gridlines -> Automatic`, so it might be a stretch to consider this a bug, since the behavior when using `Automatic` isn't necessarily expected to stay the same between versions.

The version 11 behavior might actually be considered superior in this situation -- in version 10, when ticks are specified manually, the `Automatic` grid lines don't line up with the specified ticks, which looks odd. In version 11 the `Automatic` grid lines don't print when the ticks are specified manually, which makes a little more sense. Of course the workaround if you want grid lines is to just give the same specification to `GridLines` as you do to `Ticks`:

```
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 6 Pi}, GridLines -> {Range[0, 6 Pi, Pi], Automatic}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, Ticks -> {Range[0, 6 Pi, Pi], Automatic}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What is odd about the behavior in version 11 is that the `Automatic` grid lines take their cue from the `Ticks` even if `Frame -> True` so that we only see the `FrameTicks`. For example, here we might expect the vertical grid lines to show and the horizontal grid lines to be suppressed, but it's the other way around:

```
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 6 Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  Ticks -> {Range[0, 6 Pi, Pi], Automatic}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Range[0, 1, 1/3]}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This makes it seem like the new behavior is unintentional, or if it is intended as a feature, it needs some more work.